# Add existing user to list of groups from CSV data

Tags: powershell

I would like to add an existing user to a list of groups (text or csv).  Something like this but this doesn't work.

```
$groups = Import-csv ‘C:\temp\temp.csv‘

foreach ($group in $groups) {
    Add-ADGroupMember $group -Members firstlast
}
```

Comment: What is in your csv?

Comment: a list of groups I want to add the user to.

Comment: Does it have any headers?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the following: (1) an example of your CSV, showing field names and sample data, (2) any errors being reported. Without this information, there is no way to determine why your code is failing.

Comment: No headers.  If I run:

$groups = Import-csv ‘C:\temp\temp.csv‘
$groups

I get expected results.  I believe my error is in:

foreach ($group in $groups) { Add-ADGroupMember $group -Members firstlast }

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why your code is not working; try the following:

```
$groups = Import-Csv "C:\temp\temp.csv"
$groups | ForEach-Object {Add-Adgroupmember -Identity $_ -members "firstlast"}
```

I am assuming your user's name is "firstlast"